# Change query param name with @SpringQueryMap

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cloud-feign

I am making use of [@SpringQueryMap](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/2.1.x/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#_feign_querymap_support) to wrap a list of query params into a pojo. However I wish to rename a param as `first-name` instead of `firstName`.

```java
public class MyFilter {
    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastname;
  // A few more filters
```

One solution I found was making use of @ConditionalProperties.

```java
@ConstructorProperties({"first-name","last-name"})
public MyFilter(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

However, I have a long list of params, and putting all those in constructor isn't a recommended practice. Are there alternates to customize this deserizalization of @SpringQueryMap ?

Comment: With [lombok builder](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder)?

Comment: Could you explain a little more, I tried adding @Builder on class and @Builder.ObtainVia but I get `No primary or default constructor found for class`

Comment: The [builder pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-the-builder-pattern) is used to build objects instead of using constructor, especially works for many-params condition.

Comment: I know what a builder pattern is, but doesn't look like you read my question fully.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading. [This](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign#dynamic-query-parameters) may help you complete conversion via building your own custom `QueryMapEncoder`.